# Need some clarification in the definition of "Generalised inverse."

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

> Statement*: $A^+y=x $ if $Ax=y, x \in R(A^T)$ and $A^+y=0 $ if $ y \in N(A^T)$ where $A^+$ means Moore Penrose inverse (Generalised inverse), $R(A)$ is the column space of rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}.$

The matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ always in my whole question.

My understanding;

$Ax=y$ or equivalently $A :\mathbb{R}^{n}  \to \mathbb{R}^{m} ;$ where $y \in R(A),$ $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Observation 1: In general, $Ax=y$ then $A$ transformed each vector in the row space  or null space into the column space, But this mapping is one-one only if $ker(A)=0$ or $A$ is of full column rank matrix. (Is it correct?)

Observation 2: But in the given statement* can we say if $x$ is in the row space of $A$ then $A^+$ mapped the each vector of column space to the row space uniquely. (More accurately $A^+$ is a inverse transformation (of $A$) which mapped each column vector into the row vector uniquely )
and each vector in the left null space mapped to the zero vector (of the domain set).

I'm just start learning linear algebra from basis. please help in the above observations.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have edit my question please check it once.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not understand what you are asking. $A$ is injective **iff** $\ker A$ is trivial **iff** the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Can you please try to do interpret to me of Statement*? how to understand in the sense that L.I. vectors of four fundamental subspace of a general matrix that is row space, column space, null space and left null space.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what Statement* is trying to convey.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2156438.pdf in this article(page no. 147) the author define the generlised inverse like this but for me it is difficult to understand.

Comment: I think it is easier to understand in terms of the SVD. Perhaps look at p.290 (314) in https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vikash_Pandey5/post/how_to_use_matrix_for_analysis/attachment/59d62ab379197b8077989148/AS:340211683872769@1458124195177/download/Golub_Matrix_Computations.pdf

Comment: @copper.hat The reader passing by may want to know this is a link to an illegal copy of a book, before clicking and downloading it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut How do you know that it is illegal? I just found the link be searching for "pseudo inverse golub van loan". (I am not disagreeing, just curious.)

Comment: @copper.hat It's a copy of Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan. The book is protected by [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) law and is not in the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain). That it can be downloaded for free does not mean it's legal to do so.

Comment: @copper.hat I have read the reference and posted my thought related to questions as answer please can you suggest in right direction? please!

Answer (score 0):

Are these implication related to these basis concepts of generalized inverse of a matrix or correct, if not please suggestion/hint. Thank you.

Let for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n};$

Note: In stranded conventions of SVD, $V$ contains basis of row space and null space after rationalization, $U$ conatins basis of column space and left null space vectors after orthogonalization of the matrix $A.$

Let $A=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U,V$ are orthogonal operators.

$Ax=b \iff (U\Sigma V^T) x=b$;   $b \in col(A)$ and $x \in Row(A) \cup Null(A)=\mathbb{R}^n.$

Using SVD; $A^+=V\Sigma^+ U^T$

So, $A^+y=x \implies A^+y=V\Sigma^+ U^Ty=x$ Hence can we justifies Statement* like $\implies A^+ $ maps basis of column space into basis of row space (the analogy is like any inverse function.)

and $A^+y=0 \implies y \in N(A^T);$ can we say $A^+$ maps the whole left null space(i.e.$N(A^T)$) of $A$ into the $N(A)$.

2nd version: we know $A:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$

If $Col(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}  $
from $Ax=y ; y \in Col(A) \implies A^+Ax=A^+y \implies x=A^+y$ Since $A^+A$ is projection matrix on the row space of $A$. So Clearly $A^+$ acts as a inverse function and transformed column space into row space.

> $A^+y=x$ if $Ax=y, x \in R(A^T).$

and the left null space to zero space via $A^+.$

> $A^+y=0$ if $y \in N(A^T).$

I think this is correct explanation of the given question.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please someone give suggestions

Comment: You need to replace the last $\Sigma$ by $\Sigma^+$.

Comment: ohh yes I have replaced. thankyou

Comment: @copper.hat Hi, Now Am I clear with my doubt, Can you say something related to Problem and Answer.